# Varnish response based on Cookie

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

I have the following Varnish configuration:

```
# Default backend definition. Set this to point to your content server.
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}

sub vcl_hash {

    if (req.http.cookie ~ "wordpress_logged_in_[a-z0-9]+") {
        set req.http.X-TMP = regsuball(req.http.cookie, "wordpress_logged_in_[a-z0-9]+=[^;]+(; )?", "; \1=");
        hash_data(req.http.X-TMP);
        unset req.http.X-TMP;
  }

}

sub vcl_recv {

    #Admin Area
    if (req.url ~ "wp-admin|wp-login") {
        return (pass);
    }


    #woocommerce specifics
    if (req.url ~ "^/(cart|my-account|checkout|addons)") {
        return (pass);
    }

    if ( req.url ~ "\?add-to-cart=" ) {
        return (pass);
    }


    set req.http.cookie = regsuball(req.http.cookie, "wp-settings-\d+=[^;]+(; )?", "");
    set req.http.cookie = regsuball(req.http.cookie, "wp-settings-time-\d+=[^;]+(; )?", "");
    set req.http.cookie = regsuball(req.http.cookie, "wordpress_test_cookie=[^;]+(; )?", "");
    #set req.http.cookie = regsuball(req.http.cookie, "wordpress_logged_in_[a-z0-9]+=[^;]+(; )?", "; \1=");

    #more woocommerce specifics

    # Unset Cookies except for WordPress admin and WooCommerce pages
    if (!(req.url ~ "(wp-login|wp-admin|cart|my-account/*|wc-api*|checkout|addons|logout|lost-password|product/*)")) {
        unset req.http.cookie;
    }

    # Pass through the WooCommerce dynamic pages
    if (req.url ~ "^/(cart|my-account/*|checkout|wc-api/*|addons|logout|lost-password|product/*)") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Pass through the WooCommerce add to cart
    if (req.url ~ "\?add-to-cart=" ) {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Pass through the WooCommerce API
    if (req.url ~ "\?wc-api=" ) {
        return (pass);
    }

    if (req.http.cookie == "") {

        unset req.http.cookie;
    }

    return(hash);
}


sub vcl_backend_response {
    # Happens after we have read the response headers from the backend.
    #
    # Here you clean the response headers, removing silly Set-Cookie headers
    # and other mistakes your backend does.

    if (beresp.ttl == 120s) {

        set beresp.ttl = 1h;

    }

    #set beresp.http.host = bereq.http.host;
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    # Happens when we have all the pieces we need, and are about to send the
    # response to the client.
    #
    # You can do accounting or modifying the final object here.
}
```

My goal is to ensure that I have two different cached versions on URL's based on wether or not the user is logged in. I can determine that by a cookie that is named like `wordpress_logged_in_[some id]`.

I've attempted to find inspiration for this in [this article](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/varnish/varnish-cache-cookies), but I am unable to get two different results based on whether or not the client has the cookie mentioned before. To me, it appears like it's the same cached content presented regardless of the cookie's presence.

I'd appreciate some help on understanding my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying the solution that was suggested in the article will yield as many cache entries as there are logged in users (per-user cache).

If you want one cache object for guest and the other for all logged in users, then hash on a "boolean" which is set based of presence of the cookie:

```
sub vcl_hash {
  if (req.http.cookie ~ "wordpress_logged_in_") {
    hash_data("wordpress_logged_in");
  }
  # the builtin.vcl will take care of also varying cache on Host/IP and URL 
}
```

This will be only safe if in presence of the cookie the generated page doesn't bare user-specific content. For example, if "logged in page" is different from "logged out page" only by the presence of "Log out" text in the header section of the site.

Anywhere the content is absolutely user-specific, you don't want to apply such logic. For example, "Hi, John" in the header text.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your reply. I tried your suggestion, combined with inspecting the generated hashes in as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64026458/486900). It doesn't seem like the hash data is added regardless of the cookie exists.

Comment: Maybe you have forgotten to reload the configuration? Based on the 3rd line of output it is hashing on cookie still and not on cookie presence value ("wordpress_logged_in"). That's for the first request. For other requests, it is expected because you call `unset req.http.cookie` for non-admin URLs, so `vcl_hash` (which is called later) has no cookie to play with.

Comment: If I remove the. `unset req.http.cookie`, wouldn't I just have issues with caching a multitude of different versions?

Comment: Yes. What I'm pointing at is the test URLs rather. You seem to want to have the logic as specified in the answer only when `wordpress_logged_in_<id>` is present or not. So test only where it truly varies. The URL like `/wp-content/plugins/...` doesn't care about cookie, so there will be no cookie set for it (you're stripping it). So make sure you only test relevant URLs, where cookie isn't stripped, e.g. `/wp-admin/foo` and before that, reload configuration to apply new logic.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're doing all the right things, but I would advise you to do some debugging.

If you run the following command, the `Hash` tag will appear in `varnishlog`:

```
varnishadm param.set vsl_mask +hash
```

You can then run the following command to check whether or not the hashes differ, based on the cookie

```
varnishlog -g request -i requrl -i hash -I reqHeader:Cookie
```

This logging command lists the following items:

- The request URL
- The cookie header
- The hash that is created

This should help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added the Hash tag as suggested and [here's the output](https://hastebin.com/omakebuyob.log) of the output for a client that has the Cookie set. It doesn't seem like the hash contains differences from the client without the cookie.

Comment: Your output shows that the hash for `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` does contain cookie values, whereas the hash for `/webshop/global-100-bf-triple-black-smooth-g31-2/` doesn't. So that works. However, your  regex within `regsuball()` doesn't seem to capture the right value.

But I wonder if that regex issue is even relevant, because your output shows different hashes based on the cookie.